# Project presents instance which is not included in the app

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, xcode6, unrecognized-selector

I'm currently working on an app where you can set pins on a map and retrieve Flickr images associated with the app.

For some reason there's following error thrown:

> -[Photo copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

The strange thing is that there is nothing called "copyWithZone" in my project and I have no idea how it came here. How can I find the part of the project where there is an error?

The Photo class I created only inherits from NSManagedObject and the error is thrown in the following function on the fourth line in the for-loop:

```
func isDownloading() -> Bool {
        var result = false

        for next in self.photos {
            if let downloadWorker = PendingPhotoDownloads.sharedInstance().downloadInProgress[next.description.hashValue] as? PhotoDownloadWorker {
                if downloadWorker.isDownloading() {
                    result = true
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `copyWithZone:` is a required method of [NSCopying](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/index.html) protocol. Did you declare `Photo` class as implementing it, or maybe one of its subclassess does?

Comment: Also, in the error itself `Photo` is the name of the class and `copyWithZone:` is a selector (a method) that the system tried to call on an instance of said class.